# Adding link to an image in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

Showing the error when I am trying to add a link to an image: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.Link in Sapui5

```
<Link href="http://www.sap.com">
     <Image src="image.png" />
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a link to an image by using the press event present in the image control.

xml view

```
<Image src="image.png" press="click" />
```

controller

```
click : function(){
     var link= "www.sap.com"
     //open in same window
     window.location.href = link;
     //open in new window
     window.open(link);    
     //Or we can use sap URLHelper control to redirect into a new page
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(link,true);
}
```